# Object Object result for javascript

Tags: javascript

Im having [Object object] result on my javascript.

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQCwx.png

: 
                                        
                                        
                                        ">
                                        ">

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        if(!isAndroid) {
            $('.chosen-select').select2({
                theme: "classic"
            });
        }

        <?php $distance = (isset($data['distance']))? $data['distance'] != '' ?  $data['distance']  :  $this->config->item('default_distance') : $this->config->item('default_distance');  ?>

        var distance = parseInt('<?php echo $distance; ?>');

        var distance_unit = '<?php echo lang_key(get_settings("business_settings", "show_distance_in", "miles")); ?>';

        $("#distance-slider").ionRangeSlider({

   min: <?php echo $this->config->item('min_distance');?>,
   max: <?php echo $this->config->item('max_distance');?>,
   from: <?php echo $this->config->item('default_distance');?>,
   to: <?php echo $this->config->item('max_distance');?>,
   postfix: " <?php echo lang_key(get_settings("business_settings", "show_distance_in", "miles")); ?>",
   max_postfix: "+",
        value: distance,

            slide: function (event, ui) {

                $("#location-distance-slider").val(ui.value);
                $("#amount").html( ui.value + ' ' + distance_unit );

            }

        });
  
        $("#location-distance-slider").val(distance);
        $("#amount").html($( "#distance-slider" ).ionRangeSlider( "value") + ' ' + distance_unit);


    });
```

```html
<?php echo lang_key('distance_around_my_position'); ?>: <span class="text-danger" id="amount"></span>
          <input id="distance-slider"/>
          <input type="hidden" id="location-distance-slider" name="distance" value="">
          <input type="hidden" id="geo_lat" name="geo_lat" value="<?php echo (isset($data['geo_lat']))?$data['geo_lat']:''; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" id="geo_lng" name="geo_lng" value="<?php echo (isset($data['geo_lng']))?$data['geo_lng']:''; ?>">
```

The slider data should be display on the Distance around my position: [object Object] kms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json encode and json decode you can use .

object object result get because in case we use exact select while data fetching from DB. it happend in my case.

you try putting that variable in =>

```
 $value['code'] = json_decode(json_encode($value['group_code'], true));
```

print that `$result`.

example:

```
$data['obli'] = execSelect(" 

                         SELECT 
                         CONCAT(bp_brokerage_history_id,'-',DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d/%m/%Y')) AS bp_brokerage_history_id
                         FROM
                         brokerage_payout
                         WHERE
                         status = 2
                         ORDER BY bp_brokerage_history_id DESC;",[]);
```

my resullt `$data['obli']` gives object object.
that time  use 'collect' you can either user `json_decode(json_encode($value['group_code'], true));` or collect.

```
 $data['date'] = collect($data['obli'])-> 
                  pluck('bp_brokerage_history_id','bp_brokerage_history_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `json_encode` or `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Can you explain why and in which context this should be done?

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

an object object is displayed whether the connection to db have error(like path error or config error) or some of the fields id's you are using is written wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`distance` variable instead of `.ionRangeSlider( "value")`

```
$("#amount").html(distance + ' ' + distance_unit);
```

Update value in `change` event of slide

```
   $( "#distance-slider" ).on("change", function () {
        var $inp = $(this);
        var value = $inp.prop("value"); // reading input value
         $("#amount").html( value + ' ' + distance_unit);
    });
```

Comment: its working but only for the default distance value 